# Google Analytics: I'm tracking Like button clicks, but how can I track clicks on the Page link?

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-social-plugins

I use [ga_social_tracking.js](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/tracking/javascript/v5/social/ga_social_tracking.js) to track Likes done via the Facebook Fan Box (HTML5).

That works fine, but I also want to track clicks on the link to the Page itself. I think many go to the Page and [i]then[/i] like the Page, instead of liking directly using the box...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery and Google custom event tracking you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('a').click(function(e){

    link_url = $(this).attr('href');

    recordOutboundLink(link_url, 'Title of event', 'Description of the event');


  });

function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._createTracker("{{google_analytics_code}}");
        pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action);

    } catch (err) { }
}
```

});